# retrieve value in last object of localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, string, object, local-storage

I am trying to retrieve the last object in localStorage (a user with "name" and "email" attributes). I would like to access the "name" and "email" values individually, and print them out as a string. This is what my template outputs:

`{"name":"eamon","email":"eamon.white@yahoo.com"}`

I would like it to output:

`eamon, eamon.white@yahoo.com`

Here is my code:

templates/usershow.ejs

```
<ul>
    <li><%= localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(localStorage.length - 1)) %></li>
</ul>
```

application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#signupform").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var user = {
            name: $('#pname').val(),
            email: $('#email').val()
        };
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
        //console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')));
        var html = new EJS({url: 'templates/usershow.ejs'}).render(user);
        var content = document.getElementById('content');
        content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML + html;
        $("#signupform").remove();   
    });
});
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>it IT</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="application.css" />
  <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
  <script src="application.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ejs_production.js"></script>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>it IT</h1>
    <div id="signup">
        <form id="signupform">
            Name: <input type="text" name="pname" id="pname"><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="sign up">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="signin"></div>
    <div id="content"><h2>Name : Email</h2></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

I changed the template to this:

```
<ul>
    <li><%= localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(localStorage.length - 1)).name %></li>
</ul>
```

It seems now as if it is returning an empty string, their is nothing next to the list bullet point on the rendered page. I'm trying to create a user database essentially...is this the way to go about it?

Also, I get this error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://localhost/Users/Eamon/code/templates/usershow.ejs. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. ejs_production.js:1
Uncaught #<Object> ejs_production.js:1`

in the chrome console...and nothing renders...but everything seems to work in firefox...

**UPDATE**

This got rid of the load file error:

```
var html = new EJS({url: 'http://localhost/code/templates/usershow.ejs'}).render(user);
```

Is that a correct solution? I am still getting the `Uncaught #<Object> ejs_production.js:1` error.

Comment: Sorry for saying this in comments, butwhere did u get `ejs_production.js` from? I couldn't find it anywhere on web!

Comment: Its been a while but i think this is it...i cant remember exactly what i was doing https://code.google.com/archive/p/embeddedjavascript/downloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out, changed the contents of this line:

```
<%= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(localStorage.length - 1))).name %>
```

...but could still use a little direction on maintaining a user database in a simple SPA.

Answer (score 0):

When you start your CHROME browser add the command line option `--allow-file-access-from-files`

That should fix your `XMLHttpRequest` error.

Comment: where do i type this in? chrome preferences somewhere?

Comment: figured it out...`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files` - do I have to do this everytime I start chrome for testing?

Comment: Essentially yes. On my Ubuntu I can specify command line options in the desktop icon for Chrome which makes life easier. I don't know enough about the Mac to help you but it surely does have that feature.

Comment: hmmm...i think i can do something in my .bash_rc or .bash_profile...but I don't know what

Comment: A quick search found this : http://superuser.com/questions/271678/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-dock-items Don't know if it helps.